# Initializing variable size arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I try to define a struct type with array members of variable size like this:

```
typedef struct {
  const int M;
  const int N;
  int       x[];    // Should be 1-D M elements
  int       y[][];  // 2-D M*N elements
} xy_t;
```

The reason for variable sized arrays is that I have a function that should work on variable dimensions.
However that gives an error, so I rewrote to:

```
typedef struct {
  const int M;
  const int N;
  int       *x;    // 1-D M elements
  int       **y;   // 2-D M* elements
} xy_t;
```

which compile fine. However, the problem is how to I initialize this?

```
static xy_t xy = {.M = 3, .N = 2, .x = ???, .y = ???};
```

`.x = (int[3]){0}` seems to work, but I haven't found a way to assign y.

I tried `.y = (int[3][2]){{0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}}` and several similar variant without success.

Comment: It's hard to say what's the best solution without knowing what you want to use this for. For example a single flexible array member which is accessed as if it was 1D array followed by a 2D array might be either sensible or clunky. Do you need elements to get allocated adjacently in memory or does that not matter at all? Also, should it be possible re-size these in run-time or not?

Comment: Why don't you write a function that returns an instance of `xy_t` with appropriate dynamic allocations. i.e. `xy_t xy_t_create(unsigned int m, unsigned int n);` You will also need a cleanup function to deallocate arrays.

Comment: Do you really need the syntactic sugar of `y[a][b]`? Cannot you use `y[a + b*c]` instead?

Comment: Both `x` and `y` are pointers, so `{.x=(int *)0, .y=(int**)0}` would work and later they can be assigned to the arrays to be worked with. Or, create a 1-D array, e.g. x1[M]={0}, and a 2-D array, e.g. y2[M][N]={{0}}, and then initiate both x and y with these two arrays respectively.

Comment: In C, dynamically sized arrays are not possible. `int foo = 5; int bar[foo];` This is not possible.

Comment: @AlbertShown That's been an optional feature in C since C99, though MSVC doesn't support it

Comment: @AlbertShown I really thought the very tiresome "C does not have variable-length arrays" spam comments would slow down over time. But 24 years after the introduction of variable-length arrays in C they are still going strong...

Comment: @dbush It's has been a mandatory feature between years 1999 and 2011. Optional feature between years 2012 and 2023. Pointer-to-VLA once again mandatory from 2023, allowing objects of VLA type is still optional.

Comment: @Lundin I just double-check, you are right. I didn't read about the new suggested features for a long time. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Einar Fredriksen – Did you really make `.x = (int[3]){0}` compile with a `static`?

Comment: @Einar, With `int **y;   // 2-D M* elements`, `y` is not a 2-D array, nor a pointer to a 1-D array.  It is a pointer to an `int` pointer.  Please provide detail on what you want `y` to be initialized with given the prior members.

Comment: @AlbertShown It is not a new feature, it's 24 years old. There exist many programming languages which are younger than that... like for example that young kiddo called C#.

Comment: you can replace `y` member with a pointer to incomplete array type: `int (*y)[];`

Comment: @Lundin, I know that there are many old "presented" or "suggested" nice features in C, some get rejected, some are not mandatory, and some just get ignored... however, I taught this feature `VLA` was still not mandatory but seems it's become a mandatory one now.

Answer (score 2):

You can make member `y` a pointer to incomplete array type.

```
typedef struct {
  ...
  int       (*y)[]; // a pointer an array of unspecified length
} xy_t;
```

This would let initialize `y` with a compound literal.

```
xy_t xy;
xy.y = (int[3][2]){{0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}};
```

However it will not be possible to dereference this 2D array because the type of `xy.y` is incomplete. This can be solved by assigning this pointer to a pointer to  VLA with completed type.

```
int (*arr)[xy.N] = xy.y;

arr[i][j] = 42;
```

Comment: I think your code is not C compliant, rather C++. But his question was about C

Comment: @Noname, no. It is plain C99. What makes you think that it is C++?

Comment: @Noname, it compiles perfectly in pedantic mode (https://godbolt.org/z/5o5j5T5P7). It even nicely optimizes the code.

Comment: ok get +1 then :)

Answer (score 1):

`int**` is no longer a 2d array; it's a pointer to a pointer, or more specifically a pointer to an array of pointers in our case.

That's why you are having problems assigning a pointer to a 2d array (`(int[3][2]){{0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}}`) to it.

To initialize `int**`, you would need something like

```c
xy_t xy = {
   .M = 3,
   .N = 2,
   .x = (int[3]){ 0,0,0 },
   .y = (int*[3]){
      (int[2]){ 0,0 },
      (int[2]){ 0,0 },
      (int[2]){ 0,0 },
   },
};
```

You can also let the compiler do the counting:

```c
xy_t xy = {
   .M = 3,
   .N = 2,
   .x = (int[]){ 0,0,0 },
   .y = (int*[]){
      (int[]){ 0,0 },
      (int[]){ 0,0 },
      (int[]){ 0,0 },
   },
};
```

Despite not being a 2d array, you can still access y[i][j] using
`xy.y[ i ][ j ]`.

---

The above structure needs M+2 pointers and M+3 memory blocks. If you wanted to make the structure smaller, you could use the following which only uses 2 pointers and 3 memory blocks:

```c
typedef struct {
  const int M;
  const int N;
  int       *x;   // Should be 1-D M elements
  int       *y;   // 2-D M*N elements
} xy_t;

xy_t xy = {
   .M = 3,
   .N = 2,
   .x = (int[]){ 0,0,0 },
   .y = (int[]){ 0,0, 0,0, 0,0 },
};
```

You would access y[i][j] using `xy.y[ i * xy.N + j ]`.

You could also cast it to a pointer to a 2d array in order to use `y[i][j]`. This is done as follows:

```c
int (*y)[ xy.M ][ xy.N ] = (int(*)[ xy.M ][ xy.N ])xy.y;
```

---

You can make it even smaller!  The following uses zero pointers and just one memory block.

```c
typedef struct {
  const int M;
  const int N;
  int xy[];
} xy_t;

xy_t xy = {
   .M = 3,
   .N = 2,
   .xy = {
       0,0,0,
       0,0, 0,0, 0,0
   },
};
```

You would access x[i] using `xy.xy[ i ]`.
You would access y[i][j] using `xy.xy[ xy.M + i * xy.N + j ]`.

Or:

```c
int (*x)[ xy.M ]         = (int(*)[ xy.M ])xy.xy;
int (*y)[ xy.M ][ xy.N ] = (int(*)[ xy.M ][ xy.N ])( xy.xy + xy.M );

x[i]
y[i][j]
```

That said, gcc warns

> warning: initialization of a flexible array member [-Wpedantic]

So this last solution is probably non-standard.

Comment: Added (a lot) to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way in C. There is no easy way even in C++ :)
You will have to either:

1. Declare somewhere fully initialized two-dimensional array and then use its name as the initalizer for your `.y`.
2. Almost same, but with `malloc` of primary dimension (array of pointers) and another `malloc` (or multiple) for secondary dimension (each pointer in the array of pointers). This is what *Tristan Riehs* proposed above.

However if you are ready to give up on resizibility of both dimensions, you can use macro to simulate templates of C++, so that each concrete instance of your struct will be with fixed 2nd dimension.